# Antd dual y-axes grouped bar chart

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to build dual axes grouped bar chart. But the same is not possible with antd, tried out all variations still not able to achieve it.

My requirement is to build something like this.
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqYnP.png)

What I have achieved till now is this.[What I have achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl24e.png)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { DualAxes } from "@ant-design/plots";

const DemoDualAxes = () => {
  const uvData = [
    {
      time: "2019-03",
      value: 350,
      type: "uv"
    },
    {
      time: "2019-04",
      value: 900,
      type: "uv"
    },
    {
      time: "2019-05",
      value: 300,
      type: "uv"
    },
    {
      time: "2019-06",
      value: 450,
      type: "uv"
    },
    {
      time: "2019-07",
      value: 470,
      type: "uv"
    }
  ];
  const billData = [
    {
      time: "2019-03",
      values: 220,
      type: "bill"
    },
    {
      time: "2019-04",
      values: 300,
      type: "bill"
    },
    {
      time: "2019-05",
      values: 250,
      type: "bill"
    },
    {
      time: "2019-06",
      values: 220,
      type: "bill"
    },
    {
      time: "2019-07",
      values: 362,
      type: "bill"
    }
  ];
  const config = {
    data: [uvData, billData],
    xField: "time",
    yField: ["value", "values"],
    geometryOptions: [
      {
        geometry: "column",
        isGroup: true,
        groupField: "value",
        seriesField: "type"
      },
      {
        geometry: "column",
        isStack: true,
        groupField: "values",
        seriesField: "type"
      }
    ]
  };
  return <DualAxes {...config} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<DemoDualAxes />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Here is the codesandbox link to play around.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-butterfly-sgq2tt?file=/index.js:0-1451

Comment: What you want does not look like dual axes, but more like grouped columns. See https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/column/grouped/#basic

Comment: I have seen that example but I want dual y axis along with grouped columns, the link you shared above, in that, I cant add data to right y axis, yAxis value only accepts single string.

Comment: What is the second axis in the "**What i want**" image you posted ?

Comment: In left y-axis I want uv data and on right y-axis I want bill data, according to codesandbox example, the only problem currently in codesandbox example, is, bar graph of bill data is overlapping with bar graph of uv data, which I dont want, I want them to be separate.